# How to traverse all React components including DOM components without TestUtils.findAllInRenderedTree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React v0.14 will no longer give an ability to traverse all rendered components inside of a root component by TestUtils.findAllInRenderedTree - DOM components will be excluded.

Is there some better practice going through **all** components inside of root component ?

Comment: Did I ask something irritating ? Why question got a minus ?

Comment: A great question. It's impossible to do in React, because this functionality was vetoed by some quirky React authors on purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can recursively traverse nodes by iterating over the children.

```
function traverse(node, visitor){
  return _traverse(node, visitor, {level: 0, parent: null});
}

function _traverse(node, visitor, state){
  visitor(node, state);

  if (!node.props) return;
  var children = React.Children.toArray(node.props.children);

  children.forEach((child) => _traverse(child, visitor, {
    level: state.level + 1, parent: node
  }));
}
```

Here's [an example](http://jsbin.com/wetedawoxi/1/edit?html,js,output).

You could modify the function to be a map or filter instead of a forEach.

---

As a general rule, doing things like this is an anti-pattern aside from unit testing or metaprogramming.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, yes, this is for metaprogramming - for React UI Builder.

Comment: This doesn't work in case you want to traverse already rendered component - component doesn't have children in props after render is done.

Comment: I guess you should capture it in componentWillReceiveProps, like `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){ this.children = nextProps.children }`

Comment: I can not modify code of any component, and in addition, not all components have componentWillReceiveProps method, for example, DOM component (div, span, etc.) I need traverse components just like it was done in React DevTools. Actually, I found the place in their code through the hook, but this hook couldn't be accessed if DevTools is already started in Chrome.